# Dijkstra algorithm: Do I take smallest distance even when vertices don't connect?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Let's say I've gotten this following case while studying a graph to find the shortest distance between a vertex to another vertex:

I'm a few rows in my table, and a vertex column B has the shortest distance value between the other two vertices (C and F) in the same row, but the problem is the vertex B (the shortest distance vertex) does not connect to the last vertex E (they do connect but indirectly through vertex C), what do I do in this case? Do I continue with C?

As you can see vertex E doesn't connect to B, but B has the shortest distance, what can I do in this case?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You might think, since you've probably seen the algorithm described only once, that everyone writes out the computation of Dijkstra's algorithm in exactly the same way. They don't. You may have to go to the extreme trouble of showing your steps in detail in order to get a proper answer. Or you might still not get a good answer, so I'm reluctant to tell you to make all that effort.

Comment: OK i'll update with more details, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @DavidK I updated my answer, thank you!

Comment: In your example, which node is the source (start) node? (My understanding is that Dijkstra’s algorithm finds a shortest path from a source node to all nodes in a graph).

Comment: The start node is D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, expand node C. The score for E remains unaffected because you only consider changing the scores for nodes that are adjacent to C (*adjacent* = direct connection).

Just retracing steps:

- (Row 1) D is the open node with the lowest score. Expanding D generates new scores for B and E.
- (Row 2) E is the open node with the lowest score. Expanding E generates new scores for C and F.
- (Row 3) B is the open node with the lowest score. Expanding B will generate a new score for A (232) but **not** for C because $134+186=320$ which is larger than the existing score of 175.
- (Row 4) C is the open node with the lowest score. Expanding C, however, does not generate any new scores.